# How can we optimize and quantize fine-tune model of t5-grammar-correction, like pszemraj/t5-v1_1-base-ft-jflAUG, pszemraj/grammar-synthesis-base,

Tags: python-3.x, huggingface-transformers, inference

when I use fastt5 library to convert t5-base fine-tune models like "**pszemraj/t5-v1_1-base-ft-jflAUG**", "**pszemraj/grammar-synthesis-base**", fastt5 library [Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFXQW.png) **show tuple index out of range error** in this file "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/utils/generic.py". The second error is coming that "encoder = model.encoder" is not defined and I was working in colab notebook, So how can we solve these issues and convert these t5-base-grammar fine-tuned model as I mentioned earlier one model is -> **pszemraj/t5-v1_1-base-ft-jflAUG, ...** to onnx and quantize them.